# R: Function to determine if a Matrix is square

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to run this example for the R Programming course on coursEra.  However when I try to determine whether or not the matrix is square I get error saying "Error in is.square.matrix(x) : argument x is not a matrix"

My code is below:

```
library(matrixcalc)
##non-square matrix
NCols <- sample(3:6, 1)
NRows <- sample(2:8, 1)

myMat <- matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
is.square.matrix(myMat)

## functions
makeMatrix <- function(x = matrix()) {
  m <- NULL
  set <- function(y) {
    x <<- y
    m <<- NULL
  }
  get <- function() x
  setInv <- if (is.square.matrix(x) == TRUE) {
    function(solve) m <<- solve
  }
     {
    function(ginv) m <<- ginv
  }
  getInv <- function() m
  list(x, set = set, get = get,
       setInv = setInv,
       getInv = getInv)
}

cacheMatrix <- function(x, ...) {
  m <- x$getInv()
  if(!is.null(m)) {
    message("getting cached data")
    return(m)
  }
  data <- x$get()
  m <-  if (is.square.matrix(x) == TRUE) {
    solve(data, ...)
  }
     {
    ginv(data, ...)
  }
  x$setInv(m)
  m
}

## run functions for matrix
notSquare <- makeMatrix(myMat) 
cacheMatrix(notSquare)


##check
ginv(myMat)
```

Then I get the error:

> Error in is.square.matrix(x) : argument x is not a matrix

I am a beginner so not sure how to get the sentInv to recognize and check if the matrix is square or not.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  In the makeMatrix function needed to replace x with (x = matrix()) and in the cacheMatrix replace x with (data)

Comment: Please, post the corrected code. It can be interesting for other SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer.  I just made the function (x) instead of function(x = matrix()) and 'data' is the variable to pull the matrix in the cache function need to have that me the input.

```
##non-square matrix
NCols <- sample(3:6, 1)
NRows <- sample(2:8, 1)

myMat <- matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
is.square.matrix(myMat)

## functions
makeCacheMatrix <- function(x) {
        m <- NULL
        set <- function(y) {
                x <<- y
                m <<- NULL
        }
        get <- function() x
        setInv <- if (is.square.matrix(x) == TRUE) {
                function(solve) m <<- solve
        }
        else {
                function(ginv) m <<- ginv
        }
        getInv <- function() m
        list(x, set = set, get = get,
             setInv = setInv,
             getInv = getInv)
}

cacheSolve <- function(x, ...) {
        m <- x$getInv()
        if(!is.null(m)) {
                message("getting cached data")
                return(m)
        }
        data <- x$get()
        m <-  if (is.square.matrix(data) == TRUE) {
                solve(data, ...)
        }
        else {
                ginv(data, ...)
        }
        x$setInv(m)
        m
}

## run functions for myMat
notSquare <- makeCacheMatrix(myMat) 
cacheSolve(notSquare)


##check
ginv(myMat)
```